# Droid X, how to get rid of Motorola Mobile Services?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, verizon, bloatware

So I'm used to the original Motorola Droid, I recent picked up a Droid X, and nothing seems to be the same.

To start, I cant add a second Gmail account to the Gmail app, in fact, ANY account I try to add, whether it be work email, gmail, facebook, etc, I'm always forced to use the Motorola Mobile Services feature.

I have ZERO desire to use this thing, and all it does is make my life hell. Is there a way to turn it off? The Droid was awesome but all this Motorola and Verizon bloat is killing me!

Answer (score 1):

Nasty carrier! Sorry to hear that.

If you rooted it and put Cynogen Mod 7 on, that would get rid of all the Moto and Verizon bloat and you could have as many email acc's as you want :-)

http://www.droid-life.com/2011/06/15/download-cm7-released-for-the-droidx/